# InvalidSaml2BindingException: Not HTTP GET Method

Tags: asp.net-core, itfoxtec-identity-saml2

I am using [ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2.MvcCore](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2.MvcCore/) 4.0.7 with [TestWebAppCore](https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/tree/master/test/TestWebAppCore) and [TestIdPCore](https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/tree/master/test/TestIdPCore) from [GitHub ITfoxtec](https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2).

When I run this sample from Visual Studio I am not getting any errors and everything works fine. But when I deploy these samples to IIS 10 on Windows server 2019 then I get an error on testing `SecurePage`, see my error here below.

It looks like `ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2.Saml2RedirectBinding.Read` method receives an **POST** request in the Sample program instead of **GET**.

Can you help me with this exception?

An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.

> InvalidSaml2BindingException: Not HTTP GET Method.
> ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2.Saml2RedirectBinding.Read(HttpRequest request, Saml2Request saml2RequestResponse, string messageName, bool validateXmlSignature) in Saml2RedirectBinding.cs, line 151

Stack Query Cookies Headers Routing

> InvalidSaml2BindingException: Not HTTP GET Method.
> ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2.Saml2RedirectBinding.Read(HttpRequest request, Saml2Request saml2RequestResponse, string messageName, bool validateXmlSignature) in Saml2RedirectBinding.cs

> throw new InvalidSaml2BindingException("Not HTTP GET Method.");
> ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2.Saml2Binding.ReadSamlRequest(HttpRequest request, Saml2Request saml2Request) in Saml2Binding.cs
> {
> TestIdPCore.Controllers.AuthController.ReadRelyingPartyFromLoginRequest(Saml2Binding binding) in AuthController.cs
> return binding.ReadSamlRequest(Request.ToGenericHttpRequest(), new Saml2AuthnRequest(config))?.Issuer;
> TestIdPCore.Controllers.AuthController.Login() in AuthController.cs
> var relyingParty = ValidateRelyingParty(ReadRelyingPartyFromLoginRequest(requestBinding));
> lambda_method(Closure , object , object[] )
> Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ObjectMethodExecutor.Execute(object target, object[] parameters)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor+SyncActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, object controller, object[] arguments)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodAsync()
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeNextActionFilterAsync()
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|24_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, object state, bool isCompleted)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

Kind Regards
Ed

Answer (score 0):

I have not seen this error before I'm afraid. It looks like the SAML 2.0 Authn Request is send as POST instead of GET.
The samples for [ITfoxtec Identity SAML](https://www.itfoxtec.com/identitysaml2) handels SAML 2.0 Authn Request with Saml2RedirectBinding by default. Do the TestWebAppCore.AuthController Login method in your case use Saml2RedirectBinding?